# How to track Visit Duration for 1 page website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, matomo

I have a website page where most of the visitor will spend their time on. The site uses PHP with Codeigniter and jQuery.

**Problem:** However, I believe tracking systems like Piwik calculate the time spent on a page by subtracting the time the visitor leaves that page to a **new** page from the time he loads the page.

Is there a way around this? Maybe use javascript to trigger the tracking system so it knows that the visitor is leaving the page?

Comment: Using a JS-based onbeforeunload-type ajax pinger is about the ONLY way you can determine when someone leaves a page, especially if they're leaving to go somewhere else and you never get another hit from them.

Comment: What Marc B said, or you could run a timer on an interval of 10-15 seconds that pings your sever to let you know user is still on page. When the pings stop coming in, you can assume user has left.

Comment: Why don't you write that up as an answer, with a couple of lins and maybe a demo. I would vote for you .~)

Comment: @MarcB is that event guaranteed to be fired in all browsers?

Comment: @levi: no. you can't depend on anything clientside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I added some "salting" to the $id, I don't know.. I get the feeling that it's even more unique, even though  I think it's a bit unlikely that there will be similar IDs due to the use of micro seconds but just to be extra sure

Something like this 
JQuery:
Ajax request to StayAlive.php every 10 seconds

```
function pingPing(){
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'GET',
        url:'StayAlive.php', 
        success: function() 
        {
            setTimeout(pingPing, 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

PHP: StayAlive.php

```
<?php
function newUser(){
  $id=sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].microtime().$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  setcookie("id", $id, time()+3600*24*365);
  //create new row in the database for that $id

}
if (isset($_COOKIE["id"])){
  //check if the id is in the database
  //if yes => time_spent+=10
  //if no => newUser();
}
else
  newUser();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to send an Ajax request to a page when the user leaves the page (they don't necessarily have to load a new one).

```
$(window).unload( function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yourpage.php",
    data: {
        command: "disconnect"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {}
});
});
```

You can create a javascript which generates a timestamp of the user when they load the page, and pass it to a .php page when they leave. Calculate the difference in the timestamps to work out how long they spent on the page.